# InstallShield and DllImport management

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, installshield

In my VS2012 project I use a third party dll. I do not add it into project references, but I have added its path into environment system variables (in Path), as suggested into the user manual of the third party software.

So inside my project I don't have any references to that dll, but only a .cs file where there are some  [DllImport("xxx.dll")].

In the same solution, I've created an InstallShield project, to create a setup for my application. When I run the setup, I notice that the dll is copied into my application folder. That is not good for me, because if I try to run my application I have some compatibility problem with other dlls of the third party software.

If I remove manually the xxx.dll from my application folder, it works correctly.

So, how can I avoid that xxx.dll is copied inside the application folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off any of the "magic" options so that you can control exactly what files you install. For example, set.NET Scan at Build to Properties instead of Dependencies and Properties.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've found that I can disable that dll installation inside the Specify Application Data -> Files, right clicking on the primary output and choosing Dependencies from scan at build!